# NTFS disk partition not recognised in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ntfs

There's a problem where for some reason an NTFS partition doesn't show in the file manager. However it shows correctly in gparted.

The lsblk output is as follows:

```
sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
NAME   FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL

sdd           931.5G            
├─sdd2 ntfs   465.8G            HD2
└─sdd1 ntfs   465.8G            HD1
sdb           232.9G            
└─sdb2 ext4   232.9G /          
sr0            1024M            
sde           931.5G            
├─sde2 ntfs   465.8G            WDHardDrive1
└─sde1 ntfs   465.8G            WDHardDrive
sdc           931.5G            
├─sdc2        465.8G            
└─sdc1 ntfs   465.8G            HD3
sda           232.9G            
├─sda2 ntfs   232.4G            
└─sda1 ntfs     549M            System Reserved
```

If you check the sdc drive, it should have two NTFS partitions in it: sdc1 and sdc2 respectively HD3 and HD4, but the HD4 does not show. Win 10 fastboot is disabled. In gparted it shows perfectly fine and there are no errors. Any reason why it doesn't show?

When I try to mount it though it shows the following error:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc2,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

Furthermore dmesg on syslog output is as follows:

```
dmesg | tail
[ 1886.445973] ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[ 1886.445976] ata4.00: error: { UNC }
[ 1886.449350] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 1886.449366] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#25 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1886.449370] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#25 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[ 1886.449373] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#25 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[ 1886.449377] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#25 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 3a 38 38 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1886.449379] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 976762880
[ 1886.449385] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc2, logical block 256, async page read
[ 1886.449406] ata4: EH complete
```

Comment: Please run `dpkg -l ntfs-3g` to see if this package used to read and write to ntfs is installed!

Comment: The output is as follows:                           Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                Version        Architecture   Description
+++-===================-==============-==============-===========================================
ii  ntfs-3g             1:2015.3.14AR. amd64          read/write NTFS driver for FUSE

Comment: did you run 'chkdsk' under windows against your ntfs partition ?

Comment: Done that too and it's fine, no errors. It actually mount fine in Win and I can copy, paste and delete files as I want.

Comment: Any info on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just solved. For future references I'm posting the solution. First I've tried a normal hard disk format with gparted, but it did not work. Then
what I did was to shred the hard disk first using the command `shred -vfz -n 10 /dev/sdc2`. More info here: https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-securely-destroy-wipe-data-on-hard-drives-with-shred. After that I reformat the partition using gparted and it finally mounted properly.

```
NAME   FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT    LABEL
sdd           931.5G               
├─sdd2 ntfs   465.8G /media/ao/HD2 HD2
└─sdd1 ntfs   465.8G /media/ao/HD1 HD1
sdb           232.9G               
└─sdb2 ext4   232.9G /             
sr0            1024M               
sde           931.5G               
├─sde2 ntfs   465.8G               WDHardDrive1
└─sde1 ntfs   465.8G               WDHardDrive
sdc           931.5G               
├─sdc2 ntfs   465.8G /media/ao/HD4 HD4
└─sdc1 ntfs   465.8G /media/ao/HD3 HD3
sda           232.9G               
├─sda2 ntfs   232.4G               
└─sda1 ntfs     549M               System Reserved
```

Just in case, I've also checked in Win 10 and it also works.

Comment: As long as you don't mind destroying what's already on the drive, then this did work for one of two drives that were experiencing this issue. (In the other, formatting with OS X Disk Utility, then bringing back to Windows, initializing as GPT, and formatting as NTFS worked.)